# What do two asterisks mean in a .dockerignore file?

Tags: docker

In my .dockerignore file, I see many lines starting with two asterisks like below.

`**/.git
 **/.gitignore
 **/.project`

What does this mean?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's the same as the `.gitignore` notation, ignoring the specified file in any sub-directory recursively, including the current directory. A single star would only include one level of sub-directories.

For more on the `.dockerignore` syntax, see: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file

Here's the statement that's relevant to your question:

> ...Docker also supports a special wildcard string ** that matches any number of directories (including zero). For example, **/*.go will exclude all files that end with .go that are found in all directories, including the root of the build context.

Comment: +1 I figured it was that but I couldn't find an official answer anywhere. Thanks for providing a link to the docs as well.

Comment: Since you compare to `.gitignore`, though, it's worth noting a key difference between the two syntaxes, mentioned at https://zzz.buzz/2018/05/23/differences-of-rules-between-gitignore-and-dockerignore/: in `.gitignore`, a rule like `*.txt` is equivalent to `**/*.txt` (i.e. it will match `.txt` files in any directory), while in *`.dockerignore`*, `*.txt` means the same as `/*.txt` (i.e. it only matches `.txt` files in the root directory. Thus starting a rule with `**/` in `.gitignore` is superfluous, but in `.dockerignore` it's often necessary.