# docker compose ignoring `.dockerignore`

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

Despite placing 2 `.dockerignore`s in project root and in packages, docker compose copies `node_modules` in `myapp`.

`.dockerignore`

```
*node_modules*
```

Project directory looks like:

```
myproject
├── .dockerignore
├── docker-compose.yml
└── packages
    └── myapp
        ├── node_modules
        ├── .dockerignore
        ├── .gitignore
        ├── Dockerfile
        ├── README.md
        ├── package-lock.json
        ├── package.json
        ├── public
        │   ├── favicon.ico
        │   ├── index.html
        │   ├── logo192.png
        │   ├── logo512.png
        │   ├── manifest.json
        │   └── robots.txt
        └── src
            ├── App.css
            ├── App.js
            ├── App.test.js
            ├── index.css
            ├── index.js
            ├── logo.svg
            ├── reportWebVitals.js
            └── setupTests.js
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  client:
    image: myapp
    build:
      context: '.'
      dockerfile: 'packages/myapp/Dockerfile'
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM alpine
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY . .
RUN apk add --update nodejs npm
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

No matter what I do, `node_modules` will be copied:

```
myproject % docker-compose build
[+] Building 10.9s (5/9)                                                        
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 31B                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 55B                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:latest           0.0s
 => [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/alpine                                    0.0s
 => CANCELED [internal] load build context                                10.7s
 => => transferring context: 53.88MB                                      10.7s
canceled
```

To generate project:

```
mkdir myproject
cd myproject
mkdir packages
cd packages
npx create-react-app myapp
```

and copy docker files included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.dockerignore` file that is used is in the root of your context, in this case the same directory as your `docker-compose.yml` file. But the contents are invalid for ignoring that file. To ignore a `node_modules` folder in any subdirectory, the syntax should be:

```
**/node_modules
```

However, that would result in your COPY command pulling in the `packages` directory at the top. So you more likely want to change your context:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  client:
    image: myapp
    build:
      context: 'packages/myapp'
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

And then the `.dockerignore` in the `myapp` folder would only need:

```
node_modules
```

Comment: why `*node_modules` doesn't work? I'm assuming `.dockerignore` works the same as `.gitignore`. And is the second `.dockerignore` inside `myapp` necessary in this case?

Comment: When `*node_modules` is specified in the top level context, it looks for something in that directory that ends in `node_modules` to ignore, it doesn't apply to subdirectories. For that, the `**` notation is used. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59413516/what-do-two-asterisks-mean-in-a-dockerignore-file

Comment: I meant `*node_modules*`

Comment: `*node_modules*` means ignore `foo-node_modules-bar`, but not `foo/node_modules/bar`.